# Which is the best formula for gassy babies?

Tags: formula, twins

Which formula milk is the best for gassy babies? I have 11 month old twin girls and I give them Aptamil. It's nice but they don't like the flavour and get gassy.

So which is the best milk out of these: SMA, Cow & Gate, Aptamil, Nestle NAN or Enfamil?

Comment: Hi Tiffany, welcome to the site:) Stack exchange is quite different from Internet forums. Please keep your questions *technical*, to the point, as detailed as necessary and as short as possible. And skip most of the pleasantries:)

Comment: Okay. I understood and I started loving this site. :)

Comment: Are you certain it's the formula that makes them gassy?

Answer (score 2):

Babies are often gassy. My 11 month old LO sometimes farts like an adult.

I'm certain that at 11 months your girls eat many different things. Each and every one of those could make them gassy. Try to skip the formula for a few days, just feed them normally and give them water or watered juice. They will, most likely, still be gassy.

Asking about particular products is not a good idea. Mostly because all children are different - and they react to formulas differently. Whatever specific answer you get here will be subjective and may not apply to your little ones.

You can try different formulas yourself. Check which one the girls like best, which, perhaps, make them less gassy. A week or two with each should be enough to get a general idea how each works.

Comment: Thanks Darlusz. Its really helpful. I am thinking to stop formula and Try diluted Buffalo milk.